# When using F5 reload web jQuery progress bar didn't work and my web didn't show any content either

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm try to add a web loading bar with jQuery on the top of my web, and it's work when I first open this web. But when I press F5 reload web, progress bar won't work and my web didn't show any content either(only show a white background web). Here is my code:

```
    document.onreadystatechange = function (e) {
        if (document.readyState == "interactive") {
            var all = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
            for (var i = 0, max = all.length; i < max; i++) {
                set_ele(all[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    function check_element(ele) {
        var all = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
        var totalele = all.length;
        var per_inc = 100 / all.length;

        if ($(ele).on()) {
            var prog_width = per_inc + Number(document.getElementById("progress_width").value);
            document.getElementById("progress_width").value = prog_width;
            $("#bar1").animate({ width: prog_width + "%" }, 10, function () {
                if (document.getElementById("bar1").style.width == "100%") {
                    $(".progress").fadeOut("slow");
                }
            });
        }

        else {
            set_ele(ele);
        }
    }

    function set_ele(set_element) {
        check_element(set_element);
    }
```

I notice this problem when I editing file, I want check my web and reload the page. I know there's a way using Ctrl+F5, but it's got a little trouble. I want only use F5 can reload my web successfully.

Thanks for anyone answering me.

Answer (score -1):

In your browser, you can also use

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to reload the page and empty the cache.
(<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> on Mac)

Maybe it will solve your problem ;)